# Android (Lollipop) cannot detect ongoing phone call from second SIM

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, telephony, dual-sim, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I have a piece of code that makes phone calls and hangs up after a certain amount of time.
I've managed to make calls from both SIMs (using different tricks for the 2nd SIM), however, Android does not seem to be able to detect whether the 2nd SIM is off-hook;

Take a look at this piece of code:

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName(telMgr.getClass().getName());
Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
m.setAccessible(true);
ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony)m.invoke(telMgr);
if (telephonyService.isOffhook()) { // DO SOMETHING }
```

If the first SIM makes the call, I get `isOffHook()` to be `true`, but from the second SIM, the phone is in progress, but I get `false`.

Is there a way to detect if I'm off-hook on both SIMs?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments, but I have found a solution.
Rather than use old methodology of retrieving the `ITelephony` "instance" from the `TelephonyManager` (I used this trick in older versions cause other ways were making me troubles), I use the `TelephonyManager` directly by calling `getCallState()`, and it seems informative and accurate for **both SIMs**.
A code sample:

```
TelephonyManager telMgr = (TelephonyManager)(this.getMainContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));
/* Making a call... */
if (telMgr.getCallState() != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) { /* Do your stuff */ }
```

Simple and straight forward. Working with my current 5.1 Lollipop version.